# Using two sets of mapping tiles with the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking to somehow use two sets of tiles at the same time.  One set is the base map (a watercolor set of tiles from http://maps.stamen.com/), the other is a google-generated tile-set containing only labels (using http://jsfiddle.net/ME35L/46/) as a starting point)

I was wondering if anyone has any interesting ideas for how to get the google maps API to use two tilesets at the same time, or rather a "good" way to do it, such as getting the mapping API to do it automatically, or to notify me when new tiles are created.

A possibility, which I think would work would be to:

- use the google maps labels tileset
- observe the resize/drag events (any events that would create new tiles)

  - find `$('.gm-style img')`

    - prepend appropriate `<img>` tags for the watercolor set to be underneath the labels

This approach seems rather hacky, however, so I'm just looking for alternative ideas from anyone that may be more familiar with the google maps APIs

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image why you don't use the api?

Comment: @CarloMoretto -- The API doesn't document how to simultaneously use two tilesets, hence the purpose of the question (at least not that I can find)

Comment: @zyklus -- I apologize for any mistakenly removing data.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I proposed but still don't really like (runs on `zoom_changed`, `resize`, `dragend`, `idle`, `tilesloaded` events):

```
function insertCustomTiles(){
    $( '.gm-style img[src*="googleapi"]' ).parent().not( '[style*="stamen"]' ).find( 'img' ).each( function( ix, tile ){
        var $tile = $( tile );

        var parts = /(?=(?:.*x=([^\&]+))?)(?=(?:.*y=([^\&]+))?)(?=(?:.*z=([^\&]+))?)/.exec( $tile.attr( 'src' ) );
        if( !parts[1] ){ return; }

        $tile.parent().css({ backgroundImage : 'url( http://d.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/' + parts[3] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[2] + '.jpg )' });
    } );
}
```